# How to access devise current_user from model

Tags: authentication, devise

Just start to develop with devise for my app authentication, however running into trouble with accessing current_user from a model. I have no problem accessing this from a controller.

For my scenario I need to get the current user id to keep track who has edit the blog post, which I save the user id with before_save filter.

Appreciate your help!

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only pass it down in a parameter.

```
class SomeModel 
  def my_nifty_method(user)
  end
end
```

in controller:

```
class SomeModelsController < ApplicationController
  def some_method
    sm = SomeModel.new
    sm.my_nifty_method(current_user)
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to do this in your model. 'c' here being the model object and setting it's user_id attribute before create, or save in your case.

```
before_create {|c| c.user_id = Authorization.current_user.id}
```

I'm somewhat new to RoR so be warned.

Answer (score -5):

Why are you trying to access to that method in the model?
You can access to the ID attributes via `self.id` (within the model)

Comment: `self.id` returns the id of the current instance, not of the `current_user`

Comment: yes, and the question says: " ..I need to get the current user id.. "

Comment: Nope, the question is about the id of the `current_user`

Comment: The question most likely applies to models other than the user model, thus `self.id` returns the id of an object other than the user. That's why you got negative votes.